# Why am I keep getting TypeScript error "No overload matches this call" when using Array concat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I've written a function to get first `n` items from an array:

```
export const first = <T>(array: T[], n?: number): T[] => {
  if (n) return array.slice(0, n)
  return [].concat(array).shift()
}
```

Here is the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7RgXhgHgCoD4AUAhkkoQJ4BcM2A2gLoA0MYA-FWAK4C2ARgKZIAlFVp10uGAG8AUDBgI4MfGEEwkfKByRgYxUmQB0EADYJgffAAYmK2Wo1ad9A6DDBCUIiXKCjACwVPQWkAX2lpVwgQYz4DYxAAc3xEFE8aAEYmACYmAGYmABYmAFY6QWDI6Nj4pJTofAzsvMKSxhhc8qA) of the script to reproduce.

The compiler returns an error

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
      Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
        Argument of type 'T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
          The types returned by 'slice(...)' are incompatible between these types.
            Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
              Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'never'.
      Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
        Argument of type 'T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.

   return [].concat(array).shift()
```

When I check `lib.es5.d.ts` file with VSCode, `concat` accepts two overloading parameters.

```
concat(...items: ConcatArray<T>[]): T[];
concat(...items: (T | ConcatArray<T>)[]): T[];
```

By seeing the second type of call, I've tried to change the first parameter of `first` function from `array: T[]` to `array: (T | ConcatArray<T>)[]` but then it returns error,

```
Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(T | ConcatArray<T>)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'
```

What should I do to fix those errors?
I'm new to TypeScript so pardon me if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Can you make sure the code does what you want at runtime?  Looks to me like it returns either a two-element array slice or a single an element of an array or `undefined`.  That's strange.  The problem you mention is because `[]` is inferred by the compiler to be of type `never[]` instead of `T[]` and it all goes downhill from there.  Give the compiler a hint like `([] as T[]).concat(...)` and the problem should go away.  Ideally you'll edit the code here to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask] so that the only issue present is the one you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In this github issue you can see why the array have a never type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18687),the principal response is:

> This is caused by the combination of strict and noImplicitAny: false. In general we expect that if strict is on, noImplicitAny is also on; this particular set of settings will expose some odd behavior. If you had both on, you'd see an error about the [] being implicitly any[]; if both were off; we'd use control flow analysis and treat the array as a number[] after the push(1);.
>
> The particular combination of settings means that we don't allow ourselves to use control flow analysis or allow the array to be implicitly any[], so never[] is the only remaining allowable option.
>
> I'd recommend turning off strict if you're not going to have noImplicitAny on.

respect to how to fix your problem, you can use any of the two approaches I write [in this TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7RgXhgHgCoD4AUAhkkoQJ4BcM2A2gLoA0MYA-FWAK4C2ARgKZIAlFVp10uGAG8AUDBgI4MfGEEwkfKByRgYxUmQB0EADYJgffAAYmAJkHTZajVp0095IwAsFUfKsIQ1HTSAL4OoJCwEHwRACboWHhEJOQi9Eys7Nz8QlT42DAAPjAcYLF8iGB8sYL04lKOCkoqTprauimGJmYW1jB2DnLqba7uXd5wvoLBYUA), I recommend you the second because there you will take in account the two possible values returned by the function, in the first you just cheat TS with the type assertion to return T[], but probably the type will be undefined when the array doesn't have a value.

```js
const second = <T>(array: T[], n?: number): (T | undefined)[] => {
  if (n) return array.slice(0, 2)

  return [array.shift()]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd use the second as the possible types returned are clear at a glance.

Comment: @Makyen none of the links are from my personal blog.

The first link is a github issue in the Typescript repository an I think it will be offline when the typescript project is close, about the data in the link, all the issue is important because the description of the issue itself include more info and cases that can help OP to understand better TS (him is new in TS), anyway, I will add the most important response quote.

About the second link, this is to the typescript playground, but I will post my recommended approach in case the link is down.

Comment: @OscarVelandia Thank you for updating your answer. The link that looked suspect was the second one, given that there was a long machine-generated identifier. It was good ([and required](/help/promotion)) that you indicated you wrote it, and I really appreciate that you did state that.